# Retrieving an array from a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

My response from an API is coming in like:

```
[0] = "[Identity[id=95571, type=start, userId=d12345, processId=95567]]"
[1] = "[Identity[id=95572, type=start, userId=d67890, processId=95568]]"
etc
```

Lets call the above `arr`.

I want to retrieve all the userIds

I have tried:

```
all_users = arr.collect {|ind| ind[2]}
```

But this is obviously incorrect.  What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `array` is in correct format ?

Comment: it is converted to string before being sent, perhaps there is a ruby way to convert it back to a proper array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array elements are strings, so can use string methods to extract parts from them, e.g.

```
arr.map { |e| e.match(/\[id=(/d+),/)[1] }
```